# Hitting Measure of Brownian Motion on a Ball is Uniform

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion

Consider a Brownian Motion starting at the center of a ball. I commonly read the following statement:

> By rotational symmetry of Brownian Motion, it follows $P(B_{\tau})$ is a uniformly distributed probability measure on the ball.

(Here $P$ is the gaussian with mean at the origin of the ball and $B_{\tau}$ is Brownian motion that terminates on the surface of the ball at time equals $\tau$)

Intuitively, I think of a cube. The probability of hitting one face of the cube is 1/6, because for every path hitting one face, there will be 5 other reflected paths that hit the other faces. (That's where symmetry is doing the work). Now I somehow increase the number of faces to get a ball.

What's a formal argument for the highlighted statement though? I'm having some trouble with this.

Comment: Brownian motion is (in distribution) invariant under rotations.  The only (Borel) probability measure on the unit sphere that is invariant under rotations is the uniform measure.

Comment: can you provide a reference? (for the second sentence)

Comment: Look at this [paper](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aop/1176994833).